# Renaming `graphical-models` tag to `graphical-model`

Tags: discussion, tags

I found three sites with the same tag `graphical-model(s)`. They are [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tags/graphical-model/info), [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/graphical-model/info) and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/graphical-models/info) site.

The other two sites contain `graphical-model`, but CS contains `graphical-models`.

I feel that it would be better to rename it. So that people can find this site easily from [searching](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/926495/tags-networkwide-comparison?tagname=sun#resultSets) through tags along with others.

Comment: Looking at the top tags, [datascience.SE] seems to use the singular fairly consistently while [stats.SE] uses both.

Answer (score 1):

On cs.SE, we have decideded back when to always use the plural. While I'm sure there are exceptions (which can be fixed by creating new tags an link them as synonyms), that has been our convention.

I don't think it's a good idea to selectively adopt conventions from other sites; since they are bound to be different across sites, we'd end up with a(n arguable) mess.

That said, we can of course create singular forms and add them as synonym to the (plural) main tag. Not sure what that does with data explorer queries, though.

FWIW, queries like the one you link can easily be changed to account for variations of tag names. But even then, cross-site searches are of limited use since the same word can mean very different things in different contexts.

Comment: I agree with keeping the plural. But there is some value in aligning tag names between sites. It isn't always the right thing (`windows` doesn't mean the same thing on [so] and [diy.se]) but it's good in similar enough contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a synonym [graphical-model](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-model) → [graphical-models](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-models), so both names can be used in searches and the tag will be preserved if a question is migrated from another site that uses either spelling.

This doesn't prejudge which name is the main one. Moderators can swap the names.